# How can I inject properties from a properties file into a method using Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Basically I want to load a properties file into a singleton and then use Guice to inject those properties on the fly into any class or method that requires them.

My Module looks like this:

```
public class ConfigurationModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure() {
    try{
      ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
      Properties properties = new Properties();

      properties.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("fileName.properties"));
      Names.bindProperties(binder(), properties);

    } catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my program I would like to declare methods like:

```
public class TestClass {
  @Inject
  public void testMethod(@FooServerAddress String fooServerAddress){
    //Do things
  }
}
```

Where `FooServerAddress = "blah"` in `fileName.properties`.

Now I know I can do this by instantiating TestClass with Guice like this:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ConfigurationModule());
TestClass testClass = injector.getInstance(TestClass.class);
```

But this doesn't work for me because I want to use a singleton. Also doing it that way means I have to use the Guice injector whenever I instantiate a class which I can't do since some of the methods could be called from outside my scope.

So is there any way that I can use Guice to automatically load properties from a property file into a method?

Comment: "I have to use the Guice injector whenever I instantiate a class" - this is what Guice was designed for, in particular to get rid of static singletons and instead have Guice provide an instance that acts as a singleton. You can probably use [static injections](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#static-injections), but to be sure can you please clarify which aspects of your application do have access to Guice and which don't, and whether you're sure that an injector can run _somewhere_ before the non-Guice static calls happen?

Comment: I have a commons package which several other projects using guice take advantage of.  I'd like to put @Name("testProp") in commons but then instantiate classes that use commons in the other projects.

Comment: This is so confusing ... Can you update the example and demonstrate how non guice classes are supposed to call the TestClass method? Do you expect to call it with null and then guice having to add the property? I am thinking you may be able to use a method interceptor for this, but I am really unclear on what the purpose and usecase is

Comment: I just posted a longer question that should show exaclty what I'm trying to do.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38589940/how-can-i-a-get-singleton-from-guice-thats-configured-with-runtime-parameters if you need anything else let me know