# How can I a get singleton from Guice that's configured with runtime parameters?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton, guice, properties-file

My overall goal is to load properties from a properties file and then inject those properties into my objects.  I would also like to use those properties to instantiate certain singleton classes using Guice.  My singleton class looks like this:

```
public class MainStore(){
  private String hostname;

  @Inject
  public void setHostname(@Named("hostname") String hostname){
    this.hostname = hostname;
  }

  public MainStore(){
    System.out.println(hostname);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to instantiate a singleton using this provider:

```
public class MainStoreProvider implements Provider<MainStore> {
  @Override
  public MainStore get(){
    MainStore mainStore = new MainStore();
    return mainStore;
  }
}
```

My configurationModule is a module that loads a configuration from a property file specified at runtime:

```
public class ConfigurationModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override
  protected void configure(){
    Properties properties = loadProperties();
    Names.bindProperties(binder(), properties);
  }

  private static Properties loadProperties() {
    String resourceFileName = "example.properties";
    ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    InputStream inputStream = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(resourceFileName);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(inputStream);

    return properties;
  }
}
```

And my example.properties files contains:

```
hostname = testHostName
```

Then when I need the MainStore singleton I'm using:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ConfigurationModule());
MainStoreProvider mainStoreProvider = injector.getInstance(MainStoreProvider.class);
MainStore mainStore = mainStoreProvider.get();  //MainClass singleton
```

Is this the right path to go down?  Should I be doing this a completely different way?  Why does my MainStore not print out the correct hostname?

Comment: Your provider does not set the hostname property. Why do you need a provider in the first place? Since guice is not handling your class construction it will not set the property. You will have to inject your property into your provider implementation and set it after creation. Also, and correct me if I am wrong, but your Provider does not create Singletons but rather creates a new instance each time.

Comment: I want to use the provider to provide me with a singleton.  I'm not sure how to do that, so I'm probably doing it wrong.  Also I thought that Guice would cascade my Injected properties into all classes created in the provider.  This approach could be completely wrong though.

Comment: No, guice won't do that for you because you are the one creating the object, not guice. The reason your hostname is printed wrong is also because you print it in the constructor, but you inject a method. Method injection can only happen AFTER the object is constructed (since there is no method to call otherwise). If you want a singleton then you can bind in Singleton scope, and simply inject the constructor with the property (just like you do the method). Think of your property as a Named String Object that you can inject into any Guice Managed class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written up a small example that demonstrates how to bind a Singleton, how to inject a property and so on.

```
public class TestModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty("my.test.string", "Some String"); // works with boolean, int, double ....
        Names.bindProperties(binder(),p);
        bind(X.class).to(Test.class).in(Singleton.class); // This is now a guice managed singleton
    }

    public interface X {

    }

    public static class Test implements X {

        private String test;

        @Inject
        public Test(@Named("my.test.string") String test) {
            this.test = test;
            System.out.println(this.test);
        }

        public String getTest() {
            return test;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Injector createInjector = Guice.createInjector(new TestModule());
        Test instance = createInjector.getInstance(Test.class);

    }
}
```

The configure method is now responsible to tell guice that my Test class is a singleton.

It prints the correct hostname (property test) because I inject the constructor and set the property.

You can do this with a provider as well, however you will then have to create your objects manually. In my case, this would look like this:

```
public static class TestProvider implements Provider<X> {

        private String test;

        private X instance;

        public TestProvider(@Named("my.test.string") String test) {
            this.test = test;
        }

        @Override
        public X get() {
            if(instance == null) {
                instance = new Test(test);
            }
            return instance;
        }

    }
```

Binding will then look like this:

```
bind(X.class).toProvider(TestProvider.class);
```

Is this what you wanted?

Cheers,

Artur

Edit:

I did some test and found this to note:

You can bind a provider as a singleton:

```
bind(X.class).toProvider(TestProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
```

That way you do not need to handle singleton creation yourself:

```
public static class TestProvider implements Provider<X> {

        private String test;

        private X instance;

        @Inject
        public TestProvider(@Named("my.test.string") String test) {
            this.test = test;
        }

        @Override
        public X get() {
            return instance;
        }

    }
```

The above code will create singletons of the object X.

Comment: This definitely helps!  Thanks!  Is there any way to remove the Singleton.class from TestModule and put it in the TestProvider.  I would like to use the TestModule anywhere that I InjectProperties from the properties file and have different providers where I need them.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. You can bind a provider as a singleton and then it will return the same instance that was created the first time. See my update for details. What do you mean by different providers? Do you create multiple Injectors with the same module?

Comment: This answers my question I think.  Thank you very much for your help.  One last note, it would be great if I didn't have to couple my TestProvider to TestModule.

Comment: You will have to bind the provider somewhere, otherwise guice won't know what exactly to do with it. You can split your TestProvider into a separate module that is standalone and install it in the parent module if you wanted to